# adding more songs to radio show mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a task to make a DB for a radio show and I encountered a problem with the queries. I made a radio show table :

```
CREATE TABLE song_show(
id INT NOT NULL,
name TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
description MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
start_date datetime not null,
end_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
song_idsong INT NOT NULL,
moderator_idmoderator INT NOT NULL

);
```

Now i want to insert more then one song into the table since its supposed to be one of this MTV late night shows where they only play songs.  Ill post the song table if it helps.

Sorry if I sounded vague in my question. My end goal is to create (insert) 5 tables that have various number of songs and make a query that shows me which song_shows have more song in them then the average.

Comment: What exactly is your doubt?

Comment: An INSERT statement is the usual way we add rows to a table. Or we could use a LOAD DATA statement.  But that aside.., Cool story bro. Thanks for the status update.  Was there a *question*?

Comment: if i understand well, you dont know how to insert into table at all? or dont know how to insert multiple songs at one time? also, you want to only insert data from array or something, or get info from audio files?

Comment: I know how to insert into a table and how to multiple insert aswell. Sorry if i sounded a bit vague. 
I have to make a query that shows me which song_shows have more songs in them then the average.

Comment: so you got one database and multiple tables. you want to check all tables and get any that have more entries than average number of entries of all tables. right?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for **many-to-many relationships**. You'll want to have another table for songs and a third table (`show_songs`) for linking those songs to shows.

```
CREATE TABLE songs (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
...
)

CREATE TABLE show_songs (
song_id INT NOT NULL,
show_id INT NOT NULL
)
```

Now if you want to know how many songs any list has (as explained in your question comments) you can `JOIN` your `song_show` table with `show_songs`, group them by `show_id` and count the results.

Comment: I already have a song table and ive created a show songs table aswell. The join part is what gets me nowhere. Sorry, its my first DB.